# Executing Python Script from C++ program in Windows XP

Tags: python, c++, escaping, shellexecute

I am attempting to execute a python script from a C++ program. The problem that I am having is that I am unable to execute my python script.

If I take out the lpParameter value by setting it equal to NULL everything works fine, my program launches the python terminal and then my program finishes when I exit the python terminal.

I have a feeling that it has to do with the lpParameters field separating arguments with spaces, so I attempted to the entire python script in escaped quotation marks.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "shellapi.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"About to execute the shell command";

    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;
    shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
    shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    shExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
    shExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\Python25\\python.exe";
    shExecInfo.lpParameters = "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\John Williamson\\My Documents\\MyPrograms\\PythonScripts\\script.py\"";
    shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    shExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
    ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);


    return 0;
}
```

What happens when I launch this code is my program runs, quickly pops up another terminal that is quickly gone and then my original terminal says the task is complete. In reality though the python script that I specified is never executed.

Comment: If you wrap your script in a `try: ... except: ...` you could get it to print the stack trace then have an `input`/`raw_input` call to prevent it from immediately closing. It's possible that the environment variables are different when you call in this way so it's worth seeing if the Python script is actually throwing an error and closing because of it.

Comment: I've executed the python script separately by myself and the python script doesn't have any issues. It simply uses the time.sleep(10) method to pause and then write some data to a file.

Comment: But the location of the script, environment variables and position can all be affected by exactly where and how it's called. Likely you'll still need to change the `C++` script to resolve this, but you'll know what's tripping it up by adding an error log to the `Python` script.

Comment: I don't think the script is actually ever called or passed into python. I think it has something to do with spaces being in the path name and the execute command breaking the lpParameters by a space

Comment: What about a simple `system()` call, instead of `ShellEcecute()`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

The problem with those kind of execution in a new window, it the as soon as the program has ended the window is closed. As a window has been opened, it is likely from the point of view of the launching program all is fine.

My advice here would be to use a `cmd /k` that forces a window to keep opened after the end of the program :

```
shExecInfo.lpFile = "cmd";
shExecInfo.lpParameters = "/k C:\\Python25\\python.exe \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\John Williamson\\My Documents\\MyPrograms\\PythonScripts\\script.py\"";
```

At least if there is an error anywhere, you will be given a chance to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with permissions and setting this parameter:

```
shExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
```

Instead I left it

```
shExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
```

and also filled in the directory parameter and it is working now.